# как переменную iInt перенести в файл PHP

Tags: javascript, php

```
const featuresBlock = document.querySelectorAll('.features-block');
featuresBlock.forEach((card) => {
  const contentOfThing = card.querySelector('.content');
  contentOfThing.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const i = contentOfThing.querySelector('i');
    const iContent = i.textContent;
    const iInt = Number.parseInt(iContent.slice(1,));
    console.log(iInt);

  });
});
```

Comment: *Как переменную iInt перенести в файл PHP* Никак.

Comment: Передать в запросе ajax или post, get и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Напрямую, через присвоение переменную передать не получится. C php в js - можно, например, так: `let var = '<?= $str ?>'`, но вот в обратную сторону этот фокус не работает.

Как уже ответил вам [@Naumov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/196563/naumov), это можно сдеть посредством get или post запросов.

Метод ***GET*** подразумевает передачу переменной (нужных данных) посредством параметра в адресную строку. Например, при клике на кнопку открыть страницу пользователя:

```
let user_id = 2;
$(".botton").on('click', function() {
    location.href = "http://domain.com/page=index.php?action=show_user&id="+id;
});
```

Метод ***POST*** подразумевает передачу переменной (параметров) посредством post запроса, зачастую через форму. Например, всё та же передача id пользователя:

*HTML*

```
<form action="page.php" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="">
   <button type="submit">Открыть профиль</button>
</form>
```

*JS*

```
let user_id = 2;
$('input[name="user_id"]').val(user_id);
```

И при отправке, в файле `page.php` переменная эта будет доступна в таком виде -> `$_POST['user_id']`

Все эти способы подразумевают перезагрузку страницы, или редирект на другую. Так же, можно отправлять данные асинхронным способом, проще говоря - через ajax, без перезагрузки страницы